# Clean-up Mysql update query

Tags: mysql, regex

Is there anyway I can clean this up with a regular expression? 
it seems so reptitive and I stil need to add more.

```
UPDATE  location 
SET area = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
area, 'One', '') , 'Two', '') , 'Three', '') , 'Four', '') , 'Five', '');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a lookup table with the values possible area/value pairs.

```
UPDATE location, lookuptable SET location.area = lookuptable.value WHERE location.area = lookuptable.area
```

Comment: Hi that looks interesting but I get this error [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'lookuptable.area' in 'where clause'. Can't seem to fix it.

Comment: @jamjam You'd need to create the table with the columns area and value. Then add all the possible values you'd have.

Comment: Hey, finally got it working. But I can't use as it will not work in practice. My example above was to simplisitic. It gives the impression that the "area" field contains limited number of values. When in realty the field also holds other data of various types.

Answer (score 0):

You could split it into multiple update commands to keep it sane.
Another suggestion is to create a little application that does this (depending on how often you need to do this).

With a regex it will not become cleaner, I'm afraid.